# iOS 8 showViewController: view transition objective c flipHorizontal

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, transition

I'm a little bit confused as to how showViewController: works in iOS 8, using objective c. I want to implement a flipHorizontal transition, but using a modern showViewController method.

Ideally, I would want to do this with my navigation controller. Is this possible? Do I need to implement a transitioning delegate? Help!

```
- (void)transitionFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController toViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```